# Unable to select vector when hover is active

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers

Well, I want a nice popup when one is hover but I also want the vector selectable.
If I skip the hover part, it works like charm, but else :/ Is there something I've missed?

```
vectors.removeAllFeatures();
var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
vectors.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(data));
var selectCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectors,
{
    clickout: true
});
map.addControl(selectCtrl);
selectCtrl.activate();
vectors.events.on({
    "featureselected": featureSelected
});
var hover = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectors,{
    hover: true,
    highlightOnly: true,
    eventListeners: {
         featurehighlighted: featureHover,
         featureunhighlighted: featureUnHover
    }
});
map.addControl(hover);
hover.activate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only had written the code in wrong order. 
The `map.addControl(hover); hover.activate();` should be before

```
map.addControl(selectCtrl);
 selectCtrl.activate();
 vectors.events.on({
     "featureselected": featureSelected
 });
```

So, now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Does this really work because the way I see it, once you have 2 map.addControl created with *OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature* there is 1 that doesn't work. In fact, I have 2 layers, a bus layer and a bus-stops layer.  When I activate them all, only the hover on the bus layer works.  When I do not activate the controle of the buslayer, then suddently the bus-stops layer works.  So they both work individually.  Your problem here is about the only one I found here with 2 addControl lines.  I also tried to use *autoActivate* but same result.

**update**

It's actually intented not to work anymore, apparently you cannot create 2 Control features.  Instead you need to create one and apply this to both layers.  The support for this was [removed in 2.7 as stated in the docs](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/overlays.html#interaction).  There is a good example of how to do this with [2 different Vector Layers](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-multilayer.html).
This took me days to realize.  You just need a way in your popup to determine what layer you are on and act accordingly so it seems.